# Listen for my Flash event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript, playlist

I'm trying to build a basic video player with a playlist using the OVP Player. So far I have figured out how to feed in the new video source using ExternalInterface, but I can not figure out how to listen for the Flash event "EVENT_END_OF_ITEM".

How do I listen for Flash events in Javascript (and thus jQuery)?

OVP has a lot of events defined, but I don't know how to listen for them. For example, here is the EVENT_END_OF_ITEM:

```
public function endOfItem():void {
     sendEvent(EVENT_END_OF_ITEM);
}
```

The OVP documentation is non-existent and their support forum is almost as bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Model.as file find add this line in with all the other imports (at the start of the file):

```
import flash.external.*;
```

Then in the end event, add this line:

```
ExternalInterface.call("stopedPlaying");
```

So that an event would look like this:

```
        public function endOfItem():void {
            sendEvent(EVENT_END_OF_ITEM);
            // inform JavaScript that the FLV has stopped playing
            ExternalInterface.call("stoppedPlaying");
        }
```

Then in your the HTML document, add this between SCRIPT tags:

```
function stoppedPlaying()
{
    // do something when the FLV starts playing
};
```

Comment: I wrote more on how to solve this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189442/jquerythis-and-externalinterface/4197115#4197115

Answer (score 1):

I think that [externalInterface](http://www.davecomeau.net/blog/56/jQuery+Plugin%3A+externalInterface) plugin for jQuery will make it relatively easy. If not then there's [DOMEx](http://actiontad.com/blog/category/asandjs/) class which looks promising. Code example from DOMEx site:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call(javaScript, "Howdy Ya'll");
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SWF object project google
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

This library gives you the capability to listen events from actionscript to javascript and is very simple to use

Comment: As far as I can tell, it only lets you listen to "Flash has finished loading" events, not specific events from within the SWF.