# Flash Video Player: JavaScript controls

Tags: flash, akamai

Is there a standard set of JavaScript controls for controlling a flash video created with swfobject?

I'm using Akamai Multi Player and I'm trying to find a JS control to seek the video when it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is none.

You'll have to edit the source of their player to communicate with javascript using external interface.

This post is a good place to start looking at how to do so - [Listen for my Flash event in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187941/listen-for-my-flash-event-in-javascript)